# What is normal crossing?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I could not find any reference for normal crossings. The definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_crossings) is not so clear to me. In some texts, they sometimes said that two varieties have normal-crossing (non-normal crossing) with singularity .... Could some one tell me what exactly this means? For examples, what does it mean if two varieties $V(f)$ and $V(g)$ where $f,g$ are two polynomials, have normal crossings?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at Mustata's notes on page 69: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/lecture_notes_birational.pdf

Comment: Thank  Robert Auffarth. Could you give me some easy example with illustration?

Comment: Dear @RobertAuffarth, that seems like a good answer. Why not write it in the answer box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mustata's notes on page 69 give a good definition: math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/lecture_notes_birational.pdf.

Basically if your variety is $n$-dimensional, you want a divisor whose irreducible components are smooth and that intersect each other at any given point like (at most $n$) hyperplanes would intersect each other. For example, in dimension 3, the following picture could locally represent a SNC divisor, where the lines actually represent smooth irreducible divisors:

[image]

**Edit:** This is the definition of a *simple* normal crossing divisor.

Comment: Dear Robert, just for clarity let me ask: are you describing _simple normal crossings_ divisors?

Comment: Yes you're right, it seems the difference (according to wikipedia) lies in the condition that at most $n$ components meet at a point. I'm not positive, however, since the wikipedia page given above isn't well written.

Comment: Dear Robert, yes, the Wikipedia page is not clear. In fact the difference is that _simple_ normal crossings divisors must have smooth components, while normal crossings divisors need not. So for instance a nodal plane curve is a NC divisor, but not an SNC divisor. A reference is Kollár, _Lectures on Resolution of Singularities_, pg. 30.

Comment: Dear @AsalBeagDubh, thank you very much for your clarification, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Mircea has taken this down, it looks like :(